# lisp passing value to function?

Tags: lisp

i am new to lisp and in my code i want to convert 3 first bit to integer and check if number of ones in next bits is equal to that or not this is my code:

```
(defun new (vi n res)
    (cond ((= vi nil) (cond ((= 0 res) t) ))
          ((= 2 n) (new (cdr vi) 1 (* (car vi) 4))) 
          ((= 1 n) (new (cdr vi) 0 (+ (res) (* (car vi) 2))))  
          ((= 0 n) (new (cdr vi) -1 (+ (res) (car vi ))))
          ((= vi nil) (nil))
          ((= -1 n) (new (cdr vi) -1 (- res (car vi))))))
```

i wanted to test it but when i write it:

```
(new ( 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0) 2 0 )
```

it errors 0 is not a function
i tried this one :

```
 (new (list `0 `1 `0 `0 `0 `0 `1 `0 `0 `1 `0) 2 0 )
```

but it errors

- =: (0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0) is not a number

Comment: Which Lisp? Common Lisp? Which implementation? [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)? Read the documentation of your implementation and the [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/). Consider improving your code for debugging purposes.

Comment: common lisp but i dont know about implementation

Comment: @MohammadaliEftekhari : Maybe you should check your code for problems with function calls. A function call looks like this `(function-name arg1 arg2 ... arg-n)`. For example in `(res)`: what function is `res`???

Comment: @MohammadaliEftekhari Stackoverflow is also not so good, if you have zero idea about a programming language. A basic introduction is here for download: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: @MohammadaliEftekhari: also check the documentation for `=`, because that's in the error message. Documentation: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq_sle.htm#EQ ---- The value of = is true if all numbers are the same in value; otherwise it is false. Two complexes are considered equal by = if their real and imaginary parts are equal according to =

Comment: @MohammadaliEftekhari: so `=` compares only numbers and the list `(0 ...)`is not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SBCL shows these warnings compiling your function:

```
; in: DEFUN NEW
;     (= VI NIL)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   Constant NIL conflicts with its asserted type NUMBER.
;   See also:
;     The SBCL Manual, Node "Handling of Types"
; in: DEFUN NEW
;     (NIL)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   The function NIL is undefined, and its name is reserved by ANSI CL so that even
;   if it were defined later, the code doing so would not be portable.




;     (RES)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: COMMON-LISP-USER::RES
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined functions:
;     NIL RES
;   caught 2 WARNING conditions
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
```